# Property src does not exist on type jQuery

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to change the src of the image using `event.target`.

In normal html, js below code works:

```
event.target.src = 'https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/car-location-find-navigate-gps-location-29571.png';
```

But in `typescript` it is giving error. As suggested on forums I am trying to achieve in typescript using below code but getting a different error.

How can I achieve this? Below is my code:

`Home.ts`

```
export class EditsectionPage {
  element: HTMLImageElement; /* Defining element for changing src */
...//more code here

// when I right click on image, context menu opens with a button, on clicking that button below code is fired

event.target.element.src = 'https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/car-location-find-navigate-gps-location-29571.png';
```

error coming is:

> [ts] Property 'element' does not exist on type 'Element'.

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `target` property for an `event` (which is of type `Event`) is typed as an `EventTarget`. If you know the target to be an `HTMLImageElement` the simplest solution is to use a type assertion on `targert`

```
(event.target as HTMLImageElement).src = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Your event is an EventTarget. You need to cast your target to the desired type, only if you're 100% sure it will be an HTMLImageElement. Moreover, event.target is your element, no need to type event.target.element.

**Resulting solution** :

```
export class EditsectionPage {
  element: HTMLImageElement; /* Defining element for changing src */

  //more code here

  /* when i right click on image, context menu opens with a button, on clicking that 
  button below code is fired */

  (event.target as HTMLImageElement).src = 'https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/car-location- 
  find-navigate-gps-location-29571.png';

  //more code here
}
```

Comment: Titian Cernicova-Dragomir was faster. Seems like you got you answer !